# SSIS Error: "ODBC Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, etl, sqlanywhere

I have an SSIS project that I have not had any issue with for the last year.  I can execute the unchanged packages without issue currently from Visual Studio 2019 and as a SQL Agent Job in SSMS.

However, if I open the data flow ODBC source in the Data Task, I am prompted to update the Metadata on the Output columns.  Whether I select yes or no and make no other changes to the package, I receive the below error on execution:

> "ODBC Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

The only change that I can think that may have caused this error is I updated from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019 on the server.  I do use VS 2019 on my local computer and it is having the same issue.

The ODBC Source is using a SQL Anywhere 17 32-bit driver.

I have tried the following and continue to receive the error on execution:

- Recreated the data flow task, the ODBC connection manager, and the package.
- Ran the package using DTEXEC /FILE.
- Set ValidateExternalMetadata to False on the ODBC Source
- Confirmed the External and Output columns on the Data Source have the same DataType

EDIT:
I created a new Project in VS 2017 with the same Data Flow Task.  I could run and edit the ODBC Source without any Metadata errors on execution.   I opened the project in VS 2019 and as soon as I opened the ODBC Source, I was prompted to update the metadata.  Then when executing, I received the "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA" error.   Any ideas on correcting this in VS 2019?

Answer (score 6):

Try to change the ODBC Source `ValidateExternalMetadata` property to `False`, for more information you can check Matt Masson's *(former program manager of SSIS)* answer in the following link:

- [ValidateExternalMetadata property, what exactly does this do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297097/validateexternalmetadata-property-what-exactly-does-this-do)

Also, make sure that you have selected the right `TargetServerVersion` property from the project configuration:

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)

Comment: Thanks Hadi.  I tried this as mentioned in my original request and still get an execution error in VS 2019.  Oddly enough, if I use VS 2017 to change ValidateExternalMetadata to false, save, and close the package, I can then open the same package in VS 2019, edit/execute the ODBC Source without any metadata errors.  Seems like a lot of work to modify all of my working packages in VS 2017 so that I can modify them in VS 2019.

Comment: @Hslew is `TargetServerVersion` set to the right SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2017.  Is that the problem?

Comment: @Hslew what is the installed SQL Server version

Comment: Version 14.0.1000.169